# Can't license ArcGIS Pro from an evaluation

Tags: arcgis-pro, license

I have the evaluation version of ArcMap 10.3 and it is working well. However, I was trying to run the associated ArcGIS Pro 1.4 but it won't allow me in. It keeps asking me for my ESRI account details and whenever I put it, it pops out an error notification that I cannot use it as an individual.

Comment: It sounds like you need to license it. Which version of ArcGIS Pro do you have? That said, I'm not sure an evaluation license of ArcMap also provides a license for ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: I believe @KHibma is correct.  I don't think there is an "evaluation" version of ArcGIS Pro at this point.  If you actually purchase ArcGIS Desktop you will be given access to Pro, but not otherwise.

Comment: Actually, I take that back, per this: https://www.arcgis.com/features/free-trial.html - you should be able to license Pro with a named user account.

Comment: @KHibma I have version 1.0 and when it was not working, I had to install 1.4 but it is still the same story. Yea, I feel you can use it with the Evaluation Copy of ArcGIS desktop, it is even on ESRI's website, I just don't know how!

Comment: @Akinology I'm not sure what happens when you sign up and get the evaluation software. I think there is a process to getting an account (named user) or license file (concurrent use) for Pro. I'd use the live-chat or call the # at the bottom of this page: http://www.esri.com/en/arcgis/products/arcgis-pro/DesktopFreeTrial

Comment: @KHibma Thank you. Already exploring that option, I hope it comes out positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just installed ArcMap & ArcGIS Pro trials. These two links will give you some background info: 
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/install-and-sign-in-to-arcgis-pro.htm
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/licensing-arcgis-pro.htm

You should have been prompted to create a new ESRI account with your trial. Using these account details, log into My ESRI and authorise access to ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: @Akinology If this answer helped you then you should consider clicking the green Accept checkmark.